# Why the hashcode() is forcing my JPA mapping to fetch the child entities even on LAZY loading and what would be the right implementaion?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am having two entities `Country` and `State`

```
@Getter @Setter //@EqualsAndHashCode(doNotUseGetters=true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "country", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "name" }) })
public class Country {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "country_id")
    private int countryId;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 45)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "phonecode", length = 45)
    private int phoneCode;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "country")
    private Set<State> states;

}

@Getter @Setter // @EqualsAndHashCode(doNotUseGetters=true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "state")
public class State {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "state_id")
    private int stateId;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 45)
    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id", nullable = false)
    private Country country;

}
```

I am using Spring-boot so a test I wrote to get cities of a country

```
    @Autowired
    private CountryDao countryDao;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void getAllStateWithCountryName() {
        Country country = countryDao.findById(101).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException());
        System.out.println("country: " + country.getName());
        country.getStates().forEach((state) -> {
            System.out.println("state: " + state.getName());            
        });
    }
```

The moment I uncomment the  `@EqualsAndHashCode(doNotUseGetters=true)`, the mapping behave in the `EAGER` way and even it goes to the `StackOverFlowError`. Earlier I was guessing that somewhere in the `equals()` or `hashcode()` the `getStates()` is getting called(making it look like `EAGER` loading) but since I was using `doNotUseGetters=true` flag that made me sure that getter is not in the issue. Then I looked at the generated code by `lambok` and the culprit was not the getter, but the use of the `cities` collection inside the `hashcode()` implementation.

The generated `hashCode()`

```
public int hashCode()
  {
    int PRIME = 59;
    int result = 1;
    result = result * 59 + this.stateId;
    Object $name = this.name;
    result = result * 59 + ($name == null ? 43 : $name.hashCode());
    Object $cities = this.cities;
    result = result * 59 + ($cities == null ? 43 : $cities.hashCode()); //problem here

    return result;
  }
```

The problem lies at the `$cities.hashCode()`. If I comment out this use of `$cities`, everything works fine.

So, should I implement my own(not using `Lombok`) implementation of `hashCode()` keeping the `cities` out? Would that be the right implementation?

The logs:

```
Hibernate: select country0_.country_id as country_1_12_0_, country0_.name as name2_12_0_, country0_.phonecode as phonecod3_12_0_ from country country0_ where country0_.country_id=?
country: India
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.country_id as country_3_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
......................until stackoverlow error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `Lombok` and exclude the lazily fetched collection from the `hashcode` method generated, you just need to add the annotation `@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude` to your collection as shown below.

```
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
private Set<State> states;
```

Comment: It worked but should we exclude it? Can that impact in a negative manner?

Comment: the answer is it depends. The point of the hashcode method is to create some sort of a unique identifier for each object so that you can tell if two objects are equal.

Comment: So in your application there if is no need or point of differentiating two objects of country where everything except states is equal then excluding it shouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 0):

You can set to use only included properties.

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
```

It solved my problems.